# How to drop a table with invalid block in pg_attribute?

Tags: postgresql-10

QGIS is unable to access one my DB.

Tracking the issue, I found that the broken relation was pg_attribute.

From there, I managed to identify the table causing the issue.
select * from pg_attribute limit 593 --->> table foo

Trying to delete that table returns the same error ... invalid block in pg_attribute...

How can I drop that table/fix pg_attribute?

I don't need to restore it.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a recent backup?

Comment: No backup, It seems it has been broken for 100 day, which is longer than what we keep.